# VisualSVN "Unable to open ra_local to URL"

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a TortoiseSVN installation on my server (Windows Server 2003) and my development machine is Windows 7.

I successfully Commit and Update from Explorer (right click->SVN Commit/Update).

But when I try to Commit/Update (Repo browser or whatever) from VisualSVN, I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'file:///F:/SVNcode/trunks/Edition2012/FolderX'
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository
'file:///F:/SVNcode/trunks/Edition2012/FolderX'
```

Path: 'file:///F:/SVNcode/trunks/Edition2012'.(shown in Explorer and VisualSVN).
Where "F" is a net unit to my server. This path works OK from Explorer.

I am now using VS2012, same results on VS2005.

VisualSVN v.3.0.6

Tortoise info:
TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, Build 23359 - 64 Bit , 2012/10/08 11:46:26
Subversion 1.7.7, 
apr 1.4.6
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
zlib 1.2.7

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get means that you attempt to connect to a local repository via `file://` protocol but URL you enter either points to nowhere or you lack access permissions to the directory. So something is either wrong with the URL or with your access permissions. Here are the general troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure to use the same URL in VisualSVN as you use in TortoiseSVN,
2. Make sure that you run Visual Studio and TortoiseSVN under the same user account. Network folders are mapped on **per-user basis** so if you run Visual Studio under another account, the `F:\` mapped network drive is unavailable. In fact, I guess that you run Visual Studio under `Administrator` and TortoiseSVN under some other user account.

Comment: Point 1 is ok, it is the same URL in VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN. About point 2 I think you are right, I am executing Visual Studio as Administrator and probably this is the problem...but how can I solve this?

Comment: @Oliver hmm... I can't give you the step-by-step instruction, but I think that you can solve this by mapping this F:\ drive for your admin account. E.g. run `cmd.exe` as administrator and use `net use` to map the drive. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717

Comment: Yeeeeeeesss. Thanks a lot!!! Finally I executed console as administrator and use `net use`